# RewriteRule + #

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Всем привет! Хочу сделать редирект через RewriteRule с использованием символа #.
Типа `RewriteRule ^link/?$ http://site.ru/#link`
Преобразуется в `http://site.ru/%23link` :(
Пробовал брать в кавычки - не помогает. Как сделать правильно, подскажите, плиз?

Answer (score 0):

Флаг `[NE]` решил проблему... :)